# Custom format numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

I have to enter more than 300 account numbers in excel. Each of those has 18 digits. I'll give you one example.

200-0000000000123-45

So, first three digits ARE NEVER 000, and sometimes 4th-16th digits are all different, and sometimes they have leading zeros with 1-7 different numbers at the end (example, sometimes 4th-16th digits are 0000000000123 or 0000000000345 (here I have to enter only 3, and I want excel to add zeros) and sometimes 3123123123125 (in that case I would have to enter all 18 digits)). Last two are mandatory.

So, how can I set in excel custom format in Format Cells dialog to display what I need? I tried to put something like this in there:
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSsYO.png)
But I don't know how to keep these 3 first digits on the beginning... Any help? Is there a possibility to tell excel to keep first three digits to the left and add some zero's in the middle?

Thank you.

Comment: You will probably need to use a worksheet_change event in VBA.

Comment: Can you enter the first three in one column and the rest in a second column and the concatenate them together as  a string in a third column?

Comment: Will you always enter them in three hyphenated groupings, as you show in A1 in your image?  If not please amend your question to provide a more useful specification for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Custom Number format is not feasible in this requirement
You can use a formula to link with your cell

```
=IF(LEN(B5)>10,B5,LEFT(B5,4)&REPT("0",10)&RIGHT(B5,6))
```

Comment: This only works when there are exactly three digits between the two hyphens. The formula i suggested works form 0 to 13 digits between the hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a formula instead of a custom format. Put something like this in cel B1:

```
=LEFT(A1,4)&REPT("0",13-LEN(MID(A1,5,LEN(A1)-7)))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)
```

A value of 200-123-45 in cell A1) will give 200-0000000000123-45 in cell b1.
The first three digits, the last two digits and the two hyphens are mandatory.